# How do I use AWS SDK for .Net to create an image to an instance I have? (AMI)

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, sdk

I have an Amazon EC2 instance and I need to be able to create an AMI (image) from it programmatically. I'm trying the following:

```
CreateImageRequest rq = new CreateImageRequest();

rq.InstanceId = myInstanceID;
rq.Name = instance.KeyName;
rq.Description = "stam";
rq.NoReboot = true;

IAmazonEC2 ec2;
AmazonEC2Config ec2conf = new AmazonEC2Config();
ec2 = AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonEC2Client(ec2conf);
// CreateImageResponse imageResp;
Amazon.EC2.Model.CreateImageResponse imageResp = null;
try
{
    imageResp = ec2.CreateImage(rq);
}
catch (AmazonServiceException ase)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ase.Message);
}
```

The result is always an AmazonServiceException saying that there is a NameResolutionFailure.

How do I overcome this? I tried different possible "name" possibilities but cannot find the right one.

Comment: What region are you specifying for the client?  This is likely an issue there or in header data, this is more likely referring to the hostname than the AMI name. Suggests to me that your client is mis-configured.

Comment: The region is specified in the AppConfig of the AWS project in AWSRegion key. As Amazon SDK creates...It is working well for retrieving the list of EC2 instances...

Comment: well?! no AWS SDK experts around??

Answer (score 1):

```
string amiID = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[AmazonConstants.AwsImageId];
                string keyPairName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[AmazonConstants.AwsKeyPair];
                List<string> groups = new List<string>() { ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[AmazonConstants.AwsSecurityGroupId] };
                var launchRequest = new RunInstancesRequest()
                {
                    ImageId = amiID,
                    InstanceType = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[AmazonConstants.AwsInstanceType],
                    MinCount = 1,
                    MaxCount = 1,
                    KeyName = keyPairName,
                    SecurityGroupIds = groups,
                    SubnetId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[AmazonConstants.AwsSubnetId]
                };
                RunInstancesResponse runInstancesResponse = amazonEc2client.RunInstances(launchRequest);
                RunInstancesResult runInstancesResult = runInstancesResponse.RunInstancesResult;
                Reservation reservation = runInstancesResult.Reservation;
```

Comment: An explanation would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Problem eventually solved!

it turned out thyat some codelines were doing things which were already done already and removing this part:

```
IAmazonEC2 ec2;
AmazonEC2Config ec2conf = new AmazonEC2Config();
ec2 = AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonEC2Client(ec2conf);
// CreateImageResponse imageResp;
Amazon.EC2.Model.CreateImageResponse imageResp = null;
```

Made things clearer and no wrong repetitions happened! Now it works!